# Showing more of the highlighted context

Tags: django, django-haystack

I am wondering how to make django-haystack highlight template tag show more of the text preceeding the highlight?

It currently shows "***highlighted text*** some other text here" where it must show a bit more of the previous context, like: "some other text here ***highlighted text*** some other text here"

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best approach would be to extend `Highlighter` as described in [the docs](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/highlighting.html#highlighter).

Something like:

```
from haystack.utils import Highlighter

class ShowMoreTextHighlighter(Highlighter):
    def find_window(self, highlight_locations):
        their_start, their_end = super(ShowMoreTextHighlighter, self).find_window(highlight_locations)
        # perform some clever operations here to find an earlier start location
        my_start = their_start/2 # or just do something simple
        return (my_start, their_end)
```